# Using ng-repeat with random

Tags: javascript, angularjs, random, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to randomly generate a list, in which every item is clickable.

```
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy: random" ng-class="user.value && user.color" ng-click="changeValue(user)"> {{user.name}}</li>
  </ul>
```

So, on click I want it to change the value of the item and also the colour.

I already can randomly generate the list with the following function:

```
$scope.random = function() {

  return 0.5 - Math.random();

};
```

The problem I'm facing is that whenever I click a list item, they re-arrange randomly. I want them to display randomly at the beginning and then stay in the exact same order after I click them. How can I avoid the re-arrange?

Here's a plunker with a practical example:

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/JLPDw4gkKPZdRubEtnXm?p=preview)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I didn't really get what you want to use that value property for but this will solve most of your issues:

**index.html**

```
 <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="user in users" ng-class="user.value && user.color" ng-click="changeValue(user)"> {{user.name}}</li>
```

**script.js**

```
 angular.module("demo", []);

angular
  .module("demo")
  .controller("demoController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.users = shuffleArray([{
      name: "John",
      age: 22,
      value: false,
      color: "green"
    }, {
      name: "Leo",
      age: 54,
      value: false,
      color: "blue"
    }, {
      name: "Matt",
      age: 35,
      value: false,
      color: "red"

    }]);
    function shuffleArray(array){
        for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            var temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }
        return array;
    }


    $scope.changeValue = function(obj){
      obj.value = !obj.value;
    };



  }])
```

Check it here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/i9YDktypVqEl7BJ9GNEr?p=preview

Comment: When user clicks on list, it should not randomised. He wants random name only once but not when user clicks on list.

Comment: The value is used to trigger the color. If the user clicks it turns true and the class becomes active, if the user clicks again the value becomes false and the class becomes non active.
From the plunker you just sent, it keeps re arranging the order on each click. That's precisely what I'm trying to avoid.
Thank you for answering :)

Comment: my bad I didn't understand question sorry, I edited answer and fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok sorry, I might have over complicated this in my first answer this should do it - bind it only once in html:

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="user in ::users | orderBy: random" ng-class="user.value && user.color" ng-click="changeValue(user)"> {{user.name}}</li>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/fp3UTn7CLql3zCT9EzBU?p=preview

Comment: Thank you!! Did not know about the " :: " for binding just once. I'm still learning. Thank you for your time and answer :)

Comment: Could you have a quick look at this one?
https://plnkr.co/edit/MfKHbP5Ng3YCZ8LWOvNF?p=preview
whats the difference? I also made it to only bind once but it keeps re-arranging

Comment: You have infinite digest loop issue, check your console errors, you'll find info there.

Comment: How is it even possible? I have it exactly like in the other controller in the other plunker.